# How to rewrite the depth to normal map code using tensorflow keras for bath of inputs?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Here is my python code to convert the depth map (256,256,1) to normal map (256,256,3) for single input. I want to rewrite the code in tensorflow keras for batch of predicted depth.

```
zy, zx = np.gradient(d_im) 

# You may also consider using Sobel to get a joint Gaussian smoothing and differentation
# to reduce noise
zx = cv2.Sobel(d_im, cv2.CV_64F, 1, 0, ksize=5)     
zy = cv2.Sobel(d_im, cv2.CV_64F, 0, 1, ksize=5)

normal = np.dstack((-zx, -zy, np.ones_like(d_im)))
n = np.linalg.norm(normal, axis=2)
normal[:, :, 0] /= n
normal[:, :, 1] /= n
normal[:, :, 2] /= n

# offset and rescale values to be in 0-255
normal += 1
normal /= 2
normal *= 255

cv2.imwrite("normal2.png", normal[:, :, ::-1])
```

Here d_im is the depth numpy array of above mentioned shape and normal2.png is the 3 channel image of normal values calculated from the depth map.

Comment: Were the x and y values intentionally swapped in the 3D raster of normals?  Normally python rasters are [y,x,depth]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it:

```
def depth_to_normal(y_pred):
    zy, zx = tf.image.image_gradients(y_pred)    
    normal_ori = tf.concat([-zx, -zy, tf.ones_like(y_pred)], 3) 
    new_normal = tf.square(zx) +  tf.square(zy) + 1
    normal = normal_ori/new_normal
    normal += 1
    normal /= 2

    return normal
```